# Put a looped created dictionay into a list

Tags: python

I have to create a list composed of dictionaries such as this one :

```
submarines = [
    'sub_1' : {'position':str(rand(11,55)), 'life':2}, 
    'sub_2' : {'position':str(rand(11,55)), 'life':2}, 
    'sub_3' : {'position':str(rand(11,55)), 'life':2}, 
    'sub_4' : {'position':str(rand(11,55)), 'life':2}]
```

But firstly I made a mistake in the code here above since I have errors over and over again :

```
File "<ipython-input-132-f3fce9bb6d72>", line 2
    'sub_1' : {'position':str(rand(11,55)), 'life':2},
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The aim of my exercise is to create a game like a battleship, the list submarines has to countain :

- the position in string so that it can be get back this way :

`submarines['sub_...']['position][0]` for example

- and the health points of the submarines, defined as 2.

In addition to that, the number of submarines has to be modifiable as much as desired, so I tried something such as this :

```
nb_subs = 4

for sub_id in range (nb_subs):
    sub_x = [ str(sub_id): {int(submarines[sub_id]['position'][0])n 'life'=2}]
```

This way the number of dictionaries named 'sub_...' in the list submarines will be set accordingly to nb_subs defined beforehand. But I still get errors...

I've been struggling with this for a day.

Comment: Dictionaries use `{}`, not `[]`. Doing something like `['x':'y']` is a syntaxt error

Comment: So a *list of dictionaries* would look like `[{...},{...},...]` instead, you have `[:,:,:,...]`

Comment: Thank you, it seems like I didn't understand the data structures syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider whether or not you need your collection of submarines to be ordered in a certain way.  If so, then creating a list like you do in your example would makes sense:

```
from random import randint as rand

submarines = [
    {'sub_1': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 2}}, 
    {'sub_2': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 2}}, 
    {'sub_3': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 2}}, 
    {'sub_4': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 2}}
]

# give me the first item in this list. i want to see its
# sub_1 key, whose value is a dictionary, and then i want 
# to get the value of that dictionary's life key.
print submarines[0]["sub_1"]["life"]
```

Otherwise, if the order doesn't matter, then per [juanpa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230268/put-a-looped-created-dictionay-into-a-list/47230619#comment81411166_47230268), make a dictionary using curly brackets (`{}`) instead to contain the individual submarines:

```
submarines2 = {
    'sub_1': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 6},
    'sub_2': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 7},
    'sub_3': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 8},
    'sub_4': {'position': str(rand(11, 55)), 'life': 9}
}

print submarines2["sub_1"]["life"]
```